# how to get new list from existing list, new list value are appended on some condition

Tags: python, list

**This is the list1 :**

```
[' key = 1542266464016261631, value=>>>BasicData:isConfirmAndOrder=0,brmRequestId=BR-2018-0000004,requestType=batch,projectName=Automation_Product_By_Admin,projectId=PRJ-2018-0000477,department=Emerging Science Innovation,status=New,statusDescription=Batch request created,createdOn=Thu Nov 15 12:51:04 IST 2018,gxp=1,updatedOn=Thu Nov 15 12:51:04 IST 2018,createdMonth=Nov,id=1542266464016261631,isFilling=false,createdBy=>>>BasicData:userId=999996261,email=ITEST257@ITS.JNJ.com,firstName=Iris,lastName=TEST257,ntId=itest257,region=NA,displayName=Iris TEST257,roles=[0]CG510_DHF_AP_Role,[1]CG510_DHF_Author_Role,[2]CG510_DHF_EMEA_Role,[3]CG510_DHF_FOC_Role,[4]CG510_DHF_LA_Role,[5]CG510_DHF_NACA_Role,[6]CG510_DHF_NAUS_Role,[7]CG510_DHF_ANA_Role,[8]CG510_DHF_CLI_Role,[9]CG510_DHF_CQA_Role,[10]CG510_DHF_ENV_Role,[11]CG510_DHF_GB_Role,[12]CG510_DHF_GRA_Role,[13]CG510_DHF_MB_Role,[14]CG510_DHF_QNC_Role,[15]CG510_DHF_RMA_Role,[16]CG510_DHF_RMC_Role,[17]CG510_DHF_RND_Role,[18]CG510_DHF_RRA_Role,[19]CG510_DHF_SAF_Role,[20]CG510_DHF_SMP_Role,[21]CG510_DHF_STA_Role,[22]CG510_DHF_TOX_Role,[23]CG510_DHF_TT_Role,[24]CG510_DHF_BIO_Role,[25]CG510_DHF_DEP_Role,[26]CG510_DHF_OTHDEPT_Role,[27]CG510_DHF_RA_Role,[28]CG510_DHF_RNDGEN_Role,[29]CG510_DHF_RNDSMP_Role,[30]CG510_DHF_TOPS_Role,[31]CG510_DHF_LEG_Role,[32]CG510_DHF_GLOBAL_Role,[33]CG510_JNJ_AuthenticatedUsers,[34]CG510_DHF_Role,[35]CG510_JNJ_AuthenticatedUsers_Role,[36]CG510_JNJ_Common,[37]My webMethods Users,[38]CG510_BRM_Approver,[39]CG510_BRM_Role<<<,formulaDetails=>>>BasicData:batchSizeUnits=kg<<<<<<, version=1, hitCount=1, CreationTime = 1542266464017, LastAccessTime = 1542639906308 ']
```

**List2**
this new has the starting from value which contain **=>>>**  and end value before symbol contain **=>>>**

```
[value=>>>BasicData:isConfirmAndOrder=0,brmRequestId=BR-2018-0000004,requestType=batch,projectName=Automation_Product_By_Admin,projectId=PRJ-2018-0000477,department=Emerging Science Innovation,status=New,statusDescription=Batch request created,createdOn=Thu Nov 15 12:51:04 IST 2018,gxp=1,updatedOn=Thu Nov 15 12:51:04 IST 2018,createdMonth=Nov,id=1542266464016261631,isFilling=false ]
```

**List3**
this new has the starting from value which contain **=>>>**  and end value before symbol contain **=>>>**

[createdBy=>>>BasicData:userId=999996261,email=ITEST257@ITS.JNJ.com,firstName=Iris,lastName=TEST257,ntId=itest257,region=NA,displayName=Iris TEST257,roles=[0]CG510_DHF_AP_Role,[1]CG510_DHF_Author_Role,[2]CG510_DHF_EMEA_Role,[3]CG510_DHF_FOC_Role,[4]CG510_DHF_LA_Role,[5]CG510_DHF_NACA_Role,[6]CG510_DHF_NAUS_Role,[7]CG510_DHF_ANA_Role,[8]CG510_DHF_CLI_Role,[9]CG510_DHF_CQA_Role,[10]CG510_DHF_ENV_Role,[11]CG510_DHF_GB_Role,[12]CG510_DHF_GRA_Role,[13]CG510_DHF_MB_Role,[14]CG510_DHF_QNC_Role,[15]CG510_DHF_RMA_Role,[16]CG510_DHF_RMC_Role,[17]CG510_DHF_RND_Role,[18]CG510_DHF_RRA_Role,[19]CG510_DHF_SAF_Role,[20]CG510_DHF_SMP_Role,[21]CG510_DHF_STA_Role,[22]CG510_DHF_TOX_Role,[23]CG510_DHF_TT_Role,[24]CG510_DHF_BIO_Role,[25]CG510_DHF_DEP_Role,[26]CG510_DHF_OTHDEPT_Role,[27]CG510_DHF_RA_Role,[28]CG510_DHF_RNDGEN_Role,[29]CG510_DHF_RNDSMP_Role,[30]CG510_DHF_TOPS_Role,[31]CG510_DHF_LEG_Role,[32]CG510_DHF_GLOBAL_Role,[33]CG510_JNJ_AuthenticatedUsers,[34]CG510_DHF_Role,[35]CG510_JNJ_AuthenticatedUsers_Role,[36]CG510_JNJ_Common,[37]My webMethods Users,[38]CG510_BRM_Approver,[39]CG510_BRM_Role<<<]

Comment: What is the expected output?? Is `List2` is the expected output given `List1`?

Comment: Does `List1` have only one element in it.. a String one?? And am I expecting that to be always the case?

Comment: Yes, list1 has only object. From list1 i need list2

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `List1` contains only one element. If it is true, you should just use `re` module to find a substring in your string

```
import re
s = ''  # Your string
pattern = 'value=>>>.*?=>>>'
result = re.search(pattern, s).group()
```

Comment: The regular expression that you wrote is greedy which means that your code will consider the first `=>>>` and the last `=>>>`. So, the output won't be as expected. Instead I suggest to use a non-greedy regex like the following `'value=>>>.*?=>>>'`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
import re
list1 = [' key = 1542266464016261631, value=>>>BasicData:isConfirmAndOrder=0,brmRequestId=BR-2018-0000004,requestType=batch,projectName=Automation_Product_By_Admin,projectId=PRJ-2018-0000477,department=Emerging Science Innovation,status=New,statusDescription=Batch request created,createdOn=Thu Nov 15 12:51:04 IST 2018,gxp=1,updatedOn=Thu Nov 15 12:51:04 IST 2018,createdMonth=Nov,id=1542266464016261631,isFilling=false,createdBy=>>>BasicData:userId=999996261,email=ITEST257@ITS.JNJ.com,firstName=Iris,lastName=TEST257,ntId=itest257,region=NA,displayName=Iris TEST257,roles=[0]CG510_DHF_AP_Role,[1]CG510_DHF_Author_Role,[2]CG510_DHF_EMEA_Role,[3]CG510_DHF_FOC_Role,[4]CG510_DHF_LA_Role,[5]CG510_DHF_NACA_Role,[6]CG510_DHF_NAUS_Role,[7]CG510_DHF_ANA_Role,[8]CG510_DHF_CLI_Role,[9]CG510_DHF_CQA_Role,[10]CG510_DHF_ENV_Role,[11]CG510_DHF_GB_Role,[12]CG510_DHF_GRA_Role,[13]CG510_DHF_MB_Role,[14]CG510_DHF_QNC_Role,[15]CG510_DHF_RMA_Role,[16]CG510_DHF_RMC_Role,[17]CG510_DHF_RND_Role,[18]CG510_DHF_RRA_Role,[19]CG510_DHF_SAF_Role,[20]CG510_DHF_SMP_Role,[21]CG510_DHF_STA_Role,[22]CG510_DHF_TOX_Role,[23]CG510_DHF_TT_Role,[24]CG510_DHF_BIO_Role,[25]CG510_DHF_DEP_Role,[26]CG510_DHF_OTHDEPT_Role,[27]CG510_DHF_RA_Role,[28]CG510_DHF_RNDGEN_Role,[29]CG510_DHF_RNDSMP_Role,[30]CG510_DHF_TOPS_Role,[31]CG510_DHF_LEG_Role,[32]CG510_DHF_GLOBAL_Role,[33]CG510_JNJ_AuthenticatedUsers,[34]CG510_DHF_Role,[35]CG510_JNJ_AuthenticatedUsers_Role,[36]CG510_JNJ_Common,[37]My webMethods Users,[38]CG510_BRM_Approver,[39]CG510_BRM_Role<<<,formulaDetails=>>>BasicData:batchSizeUnits=kg<<<<<<, version=1, hitCount=1, CreationTime = 1542266464017, LastAccessTime = 1542639906308 ']
new_list = [re.search(r'=>>>(.*?),\w*=>>>', row).group(1) for row in list1]
print(new_list)
```

You can use regex to extract item form your list based on the logic of your need. I have Used List Comprehensions to loop through each item of the `list1`

For More, Read:

1. [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)
2. [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)